# Get ID lexemes in lexer class ANTLR3 that implemented to a jTable

Tags: java, antlr, token, lexer

I am building a java clone code detector in swing that implemented the ANTLR. This is the Screenshot :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnumgsjmpps33v5/SemogaYaAllah.png

if you see the screenshot, there are a main file that compared to another files. The way that I do is compared thats token main file to another file. The problem is, I am failed to get the ID Lexemes or tokens from my lexer class.
This is my ANTLR3JavaLexer

```
public class Antlr3JavaLexer extends Lexer {
public static final int PACKAGE=84;
public static final int EXPONENT=173;
public static final int STAR=49;
public static final int WHILE=103;
public static final int MOD=32;
public static final int MOD_ASSIGN=33;
public static final int CASE=58;
public static final int CHAR=60;
```

I ve created a JavaParser.class like this to use that lexer:

```
public final class JavaParser extends AParser { //Parser is my Abstract Class

JavaParser() {

}

@Override
protected boolean parseFile(JCCDFile f, final ASTManager treeContainer)throws ParseException, IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getFile()));
    String filePath = f.getNama(); // getName of file


    final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();

    lexer.preserveWhitespacesAndComments = false;

    try {
        lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

//This is the problem
//When I am activated this code pieces, I get the output like this 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/80uyva56mk1r5xy/Bismillah2.png
  /* 
 StringBuilder sbu = new StringBuilder();
 while (true) {
        org.antlr.runtime.Token token = lexer.nextToken();
        if (token.getType() == Antlr3JavaLexer.EOF) {
            break;
        }
        sbu.append(token.getType());
        System.out.println(token.getType() + ": :" + token.getText());
    }*/

    final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
    tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);
    tokens.LT(10); // force load

    // Create the parser
    Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(tokens.toString());

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Main_Menu.jTable2.getModel();
    List<final_tugas_akhir.Report2> theListData = new ArrayList<Report2>();
    final_tugas_akhir.Report2 theResult = new final_tugas_akhir.Report2();

    theResult.setFile(filePath);
    theResult.setId(sb.toString());
    theResult.setNum(sbu.toString());
    theListData.add(theResult);

    for (Report2 report : theListData) {
        System.out.println(report.getFile());
        System.out.println(report.getId());
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            report.getFile(),
            report.getId(),
            report.getNum(),
        });
    }

    //  in CompilationUnit
    CommonTree tree;
    try {
        tree = (CommonTree) parser.compilationUnit().getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);

    } catch (RecognitionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    walkThroughChildren(tree, treeContainer, parser.getTokenStream()); //this is my method to check the similiar tokens
    in.close();
    this.posisiFix(treeContainer); //fix position        
    return true;
}
```

Once again, this is the error code my java program link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/80uyva56mk1r5xy/Bismillah2.png.
The tokens always give me a null value.

Comment: anyone on stackoverflow